# how to save a listbox to existing file

Tags: vb.net, save

in my form1, i have a listbox showing my files, and click the file in the listbox it pump to form2 for making change. after i finish changing, i want to save the file in original name.

but my code doesn't work

the error says "The process cannot access the file 'U:\test\111.txt' because it is being used by another process."

here is the code for listbox in form1

```
    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    myDirectory = "U:\test"
    Dim myFile As String = myDirectory & "\" & ListBox1.SelectedItem & ".txt"
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(myFile)
    Form2.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Do Until sr.EndOfStream
        Form2.ListBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
    Loop

    Form2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

here is the code for my save button

```
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("U:\test\" & Form1.ListBox1.SelectedItem & ".txt", True)
        For Each itm As String In Me.ListBox1.Items
            SW.WriteLine(itm)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the append option to false in the StreamWriter constructor

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("U:\test\" & Form1.ListBox1.SelectedItem & ".txt", False)
        For Each itm As String In Me.ListBox1.Items
            SW.WriteLine(itm)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: thx, but my code seems not actually save the file, it is write the data in the existing file. for example i have 11,22,33 in listbox, after i click save button, the next time i open it, it will display 11,22,33 11,22,33 in the list box.

Answer (score 0):

> the error says "The process cannot access the file 'U:\test\111.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process."

You should close your opened file handle in `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` first ..

```
sr.Close()
```